# Will emptying an Array = [ ] cause memory leak?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, memory-leaks, array-splice

Hey guys I was wondering if removing all objects on the stage like so:

```
//bomb
for each (var bomb:mcBomb in aBombArray)
{
    bomb.parent.removeChild(bomb);
    aBombArray = [];
    bomb = null;
}
```

at the end of the game cause a Memory Leak? Is this removing all objects in the array and setting it back to 0? Should I instead use `aBombArray.length = 0;`?

I have all my arrays removed like this at the end of the game. I notice that when you get the 'Game Over' screen the memory doesn't decrease it instead still climbs. Not sure if this might be the problem.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code, but I think what you are asking is whether setting an `Array` property to `[]` will be enough to dereference all the elements that used to be in that array. The answer is yes, as long as there were no other references to that array or elements in the array. For example:

```
var bombs:Array = [a, b, c];
var bombs2:Array = bombs;
bombs = [];
// a, b, c remain in memory because they are still referenced by bombs2
```

A slightly more thorough way to clear the array is to set its length to 0. In that case all references to the array will be cleared, because you didn't re-assign the property, you modified the array directly:

```
var bombs:Array = [a, b, c];
var bombs2:Array = bombs;
bombs.length = 0;
// both bombs and bombs2 are cleared, so a, b, c will be removed from memory
```

Of course, any references to the elements within the array, including in other arrays, will keep those objects in memory.

```
var bombs:Array = [a, b, c];
var bombs2:Array = [a, b];
bombs.length = 0;
// bombs2 still references a, b so they will remain in memory
```

Going back to your original code, the following should work, assuming there are no other references to the elements in the array as in the previous examples:

```
for each (var bomb:mcBomb in aBombArray) {
    bomb.parent.removeChild(bomb);
}
aBombArray.length = 0;
```

Note that:

1. The array is not cleared until the loop finishes.
2. There's no need to set `bomb = null` in each iteration, because each iteration will immediately assign a new value, and as a local variable it will be de-referenced when the function scope returns anyway.

Finally, you mention that you don't see the memory go down at the end. Garbage collection happens at some unknown time in the future when the runtime decides is a good time, so you don't see memory released as soon as the objects are completely de-referenced. In debugging environments you can use [`System.gc()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29) to test if memory is freed.

**I recommend that you use Adobe Scout or a profiler to see what objects are actually sticking around in memory.**

Comment: Again thank you so much Aaron for the detailed information. I added Null to all my for loops. Interesting I had no Idea you could add aBombArray.length = 0; outside the loop. So it would be safe to add that even if the function is within an ENTER_FRAME event? It won't access the aBombArray.length = 0; first then go through the for loop?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... in my example I set `array.length = 0` after the loop because otherwise it will affect the loop: if you clear the array before the loop, the loop would not have anything to iterate over; if you clear the array inside the loop, it would clear it during the first iteration of the loop and never iterate over any other elements in the array.

Comment: Yeah that was my question. You answered it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the last portion of the answer nailed it for me, as I was quite confused about `process.memoryUsage()`'s heap property still displaying the full memory allocation of the just-dereferenced gigantic array object. I was superficially thinking that memory deallocation takes place instantly, but rather gets triggered by other factors i.e. subsequent memory allocation of reasonable size.