# Will the contents inside the Array garbage collected when we do someArray = []

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

someArray has some items in it.
so someArray.splice(0) and someArray = [] does the same which is to make the someArray empty.

someArray.splice(0) takes considerably more time than someArray = [].

By doing someArray = [], the contents inside someArray will be Garbaged collected?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491445/will-emptying-an-arrray-cause-memory-leak/28491902#28491902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will if no other variable holds a pointer to some of array's elements.
For example,

```
var a:Array = [new Object(), new Object(), new Object()];
var b:Object = a[1];
a = [];
```

`a[0]` and `a[2]` will be garbage collected, `a[1]` will not, because variable b holds a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [];
```

creates new empty one instead of clearing, hence garbage collector leaves it alive, need to use:

```
array.length = 0; // or array.splice(0);
```

cause you might have references to the array and they need to be updated also

Check first:

```
var someArray:Array=[1,2,3];
var copyOfSomeArray:Array=someArray;
someArray=[];
trace (copyOfSomeArray); //gives 1,2,3
```

and now this:

```
var someArray:Array=[1,2,3];
var copyOfSomeArray:Array=someArray;
someArray.length = 0;
trace (copyOfSomeArray); //gives nothing
```

and et the end don't forget to explicitly null array for a Garbage Collector.

```
someArray=null;
```

Comment: Explanation for your first example:
someArray and copyOfSomeArray are referencing to the same memory area.
you have dereferenced someArray but still copyOfSomeArray is still referencing

so doing someArray = [];//This creates a new memory area for someArray.

trace(copyOfSomeArray)//gives 1,2,3; since copyOfSomeArray is still referencing

var someArray:Array=[1,2,3];

Explanation for your second example

since both are referencing to same memory area, you change one others will get affected.

so doing someArray.length = 0;//affects copyOfSomeArray too.